# How to count row data in sap ui5

Tags: sapui5

Here is my code,

```
var oTable_order = this.getView().byId("TabOrd");
oTable_order.setModel(oModel_order);
oTable_order.bindAggregation("items", "/d/results", oTemplate);
this.getView().setModel(oModel_order);
```

Please suggest How to get the count set to the IconTabFilter Count element with the length of the loaded data.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Bind to `{/d/results/length}`, like you would with any property in your model

Comment: that is correct and i have already used it (forgot to mention) I am displaying 3 tabs each having table to display same data but filtered with type of the data

hence it works only on the first tab and it always shows the length of the last tab. 

i need some other way to display count value

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run a couple of ODataModel.read statements on your model for each of your filter tabs, something like:

```
// These filters are the filter that should be applied for your icon count
var _mFilters = {
    matMaster: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("MatMaster", "EQ", true)],
    equipment: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Equipment", "EQ", true)],
    prodOrder: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("OrderType", "EQ", "P")]
};

// These are the counts that should be displayed on your filter buttons.
// Bind them from your view
var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
    matMaster: 0,
    equipment: 0,
    prodOrder: 0
});
this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view");

// This will run the 3 read statement. One with each of the filters in 
// effect. The result will go into the oViewModel values declared above.
jQuery.each(_mFilters, function (sFilterKey, oFilter) {
    oModel.read("/Orders/$count", {
        filters: oFilter,
        success: function (oData) {
            var sPath = "/" + sFilterKey;
            oViewModel.setProperty(sPath, oData);
        }
    });
});
```

If you then bind the count properties of the IconTabFilter controls, e.g.: {view>matMaster}. Every count should represent another filter value.

Note: don't worry about this being 3 reads. The UI5 framework will nicely  bundle these into a single batch going to the back-end, resulting in just one request, not three.

Comment: There is some syntax error in  -- _mFilters: {
    matMaster: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("MatMaster", "EQ", true)],
    equipment: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Equipment", "EQ", true)],
    prodOrder: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("OrderType", "EQ", "P")]
},

Comment: Please the code is not complete and shouldn't be directly copied and pasted into your project. It's merely meant to give you a general idea on how to solve this. Changed the code slightly nevertheless.